# Hyperledger Fabric: Exact meaning of "simulation" and "execution"

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

Hyperledger Fabric is known to employ an `<execute-order>` structure wherein a transaction is ***"executed"*** speculatively and then it is checked for correctness:

https://medium.com/@rahulmahadev/side-effects-due-to-speculative-execution-in-hyperledger-fabric-a0b7cd6ab1ea

[Hyperledger Fabric execute-order diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2HF5.png)

In the execution block in the diagram above, what exactly a ***"simulation"*** does? How different from a simulation and an execution? Is there a possibility that a transaction is NOT executed if a simulation fails?

Your advice will be most appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Transaction executions usually means to execute a function and afterwards apply changes to the database according to the transaction.

A simulation means to execute the function without applying the changes to the database, and instead record them.

Recall, most blockchains follow the order-execute model (like Bitcoin, Ethereum) where all nodes execute transactions and apply changes to their database immediately.

In contrast, Hyperledger Fabric executes the transactions on a subset of the peers of the network, and the results of the execution are recorded, cryptographically signed and then distributed to all peers via the ordering service.